# How to show Google Local business marker and InfoWindow in custom Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-local-business

I want to show the location of my business on my website using google maps. Instead of creating the marker, infowindow, etc... by hand, I would like to reuse the one found in Google Local business listings.

For instance, [this business](http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=15966491111843230210&q=fogcreek+new+york&hl=en&cd=1&ei=ZrN_TJbiN8mJ_gal3bSeAw&sll=40.706758,-74.012754&sspn=0.016709,0.014918&ie=UTF8&ll=40.71942,-74.045792&spn=0,0&z=15&iwloc=A) could use [this map](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=fogcreek+new+york&hl=en&cd=1&ei=g7N_TJWpI9uhsQaRnujZDA&sll=40.706758,-74.012754&sspn=0.016709,0.014918&ie=UTF8&view=map&cid=15966491111843230210&ved=0CG0QpQY&hq=fogcreek+new+york&hnear=&z=16&iwloc=A). The advantages are numerous : it is already done, it will be updated when you update the listing, it has directions, etc...

Does anybody know how to do that using the JavaScript API (v3) ? I could obviously use the iframe code they provide, but I would love having a bit more control on the result, especially the controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can either use the embed as is, or build a custom map using the JavaScript API.